# imageDownloader For a Custom AnnotationView

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview

I created this custom annotationView that can contain a logo and a label in the screenshot the logo is stored locally,

screenshot : http://hpics.li/3c45def

now I want to display the logo stored on the server, I tried  to integrate the tableview imagedownloader but I failed, someone has an idea of ​​where to start

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLRequest to download the raw data for the image from the server. Once downloaded you can set the image in your tableview.

You start by having a look at this [post](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-asynchronously/).